# TCP vs UDP - Issues that arise from using both

Tags: tcp, network-programming, udp, multiplayer

When I'm learning about various technologies, I often try to think of how applications I use regularly implement such things. I've played a few MMOs along with some FPSs. I did some looking around and happened upon this thread:

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/319003-mmorpg-and-the-ol-udp-vs-tcp

I have been seeing that UDP shines when some loss of packets is permissible. There's less overhead involved and updates are done more quickly. After looking around for a bit and reading various articles and threads, I've come to see that character positioning will often be done with UDP. Games like FPSs will often be done with UDP because of all the rapid changes that are occuring.

I've seen multiple times now where someone pointed out issues that can occur when using UDP and TCP simultaneously. What might some of these problems be? Are these issues that would mostly be encountered by novice programmers? It seems to me that it would be ideal to use a combination of UDP and TCP, gaining the advantages of each. However, if using the two together adds a significant amount of complexity to the code to deal with problems caused, it may not be worth it in certain situations.

Comment: If you are specifically interested in game-related answers you would get more from asking this on the gamedev stackexchange.

Comment: I'll check them out. I did start this out with a focus on game design, but that was more to lay out the the situation. The last block of text in my question can apply to any TCP or UDP applications, and any answers given whether game related or not will work just fine for my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many games use UDP and TCP together. Since it is mandatory for every game to deliver the actions of a player to everyone, it has to be done in one way or the other. It now depends on what kind of game you want to make. In a RTS, surely TCP would be much wiser, since you cannot lose information about your opponents movement. In an RPG, it is not that incredibly important to keep track of everything every second of the game.

Bottom line is, if data has to arrive at the client, in any case, (position updates, upgrades aso.), you have to send it via TCP, or, you implement your own *reliable* protocol based on UDP. I have constructed quite a few network stacks for games, and I have to say, what you use depends on the usecase and what you are trying to accomplish. I mostly did a *heartbeat* over UDP, so the remote server/client knows that I am still there. The problem with UDP is, that packets get lost and not resent. If a packet drops, it is lost for ever. You have to take that into account. If you send some information over UDP, it has to be information that is allowed to be lost. Everything else goes via TCP.

And so the madness began. If you want to get most out of both, you will have to adapt them. TCP can be slow sometimes, and you have to wait, if packets get fragmented or do not arrive in order, until the OS has reassembled them. In some cases it could be advisable to build your own *reliable* protocol on top of UDP. That would allow you complete control over your traffic. Most firewalls do not drop UDP or anything else, but as with TCP, any traffic that is not declared to be safe (Opening Ports, packet redirects, aso.), gets dropped. I would suggest you read up the [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) and [UDP-Lite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#UDP-Lite) article up at wikipedia and then decide which ones you want to use for what. AFAIK Battle.net uses a combination of the two.

Answer (score 2):

Many services use udp and tcp together, but doing so without adding congestion control to your udp implementation can cause major problems for tcp. Long story short, udp can and often will clog the routers at each endpoint making tcp's congestion control to go haywire and significantly limit the throughout of the tcp connection. The udp based congestion can also cause significant increase in packet loss for  tcp, limiting tcp's throughput even more as it will need to have these packets retransmitted. Using them together isn't  a bad idea and is even becoming somewhat common, but you'll want to keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The first possible issue I can think of is that, because UDP doesn't have the overhead inherent in the "transmission control" that TCP does, UDP has higher data bandwidth and lower latency. So, it is possible for a UDP datagram that was sent after a TCP message to be available on the remote computer's input buffers before the TCP message is received in full.

This may cause problems if you use TCP to control or monitor UDP transmission; for instance, you might tell the server via TCP that you'll be sending some datagrams via UDP on port X. If the remote computer isn't already listening on port X, it may not receive some of these datagrams, because they arrived before it was told to listen; if it is listening, but not expecting traffic from you, it may discard them because they showed up before it was told to expect them. This may have an adverse effect on your program's flow or your user's experience.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Now that I read this, I'm reminded of something else I read in a book. It stated that the TCP congestion control was "for the greater good". UDP on the other hand, can hog up a lot of bandwidth and cause issues for the TCP users in the same network. I think I read that something related to this is why many firewalls block UDP.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you like to transfer game data TCP will be the only solution. Imagine that you send a command (e.g gained x item :P) at the server and this packet never reach its destination. (udp has no guaranties).

Also imagine the scenario that two or more UDP packets reach their destination in wrong order.

But if with your game you integrate any VoIP or Video Call capabilities you can use at these UDP.